# Is it possible to decode prettify?

Tags: prettify, google-code-prettify

Is there a (already implemented) solution that decodes already encoded syntax from googles code-prettify?

```
<?php
$foo = "bar";
```

gets to

```
<pre class="prettyprint prettyprinted"><span class="pun">&lt;?</span><span class="pln">php
$foo </span><span class="pun">=</span><span class="pln"> </span><span class="str">"bar"</span><span class="pun">;</span></pre>
```

Now I want decode it again to

```
<?php
$foo = "bar";
```

Comment: `textContent` should work

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('prettyprinted')[0].textContent`

Comment: works pretty well. Post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) DOM property will let you access the plain text content of a DOM node, so just get the prettified `<pre>` element.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('prettyprinted')[0].textContent
```

Since `textContent` just concatenates text nodes, it works for prettyprinted `<pre>` and `<xmp>` elements and `<code>` elements that have CSS style `whitespace:pre`.

It should work for elements with `linenums` where prettify inserts an `<li>` element per line because the text still contains the original line-breaks, but I would test that separately if you rely upon that.